Distance between probability distributions
I am trying to understand the differences between three distances between probability distributions, for instance what are their advantages and inconvenients, what they do emphasize and what they don't, essentially from a practical point of view: when to use this one versus the other, it is easy to compute/estimate numerically, etc. Here I am only interested in absolutely continuous 1D probability distributions. Given two such probability distributions $P$ and $Q$, the three distances I am interested in are:

The Total Variation Distance (TVD):
$$
\mathsf{TVD}(P,Q)=\int_\mathbb{R}\big|p(x)-q(x)\big|\,\mathrm{d}x,
$$
where $p$ is the probability density function (PDF) associated to $P$ and $q$ the one associated to $Q$.
The Wasserstein-1 distance:
$$
\mathsf{W}_1(P,Q)=\int_0^1\big|F^{-1}(q)-G^{-1}(q)\big|\,\mathrm{d}q=\int_\mathbb{R}\big|F(x)-G(x)\big|\,\mathrm{d}x,
$$
where $F$ is the cumulative probability function (CDF) associated to $P$ and $G$ the one associated to $Q$.
The Maximum Mean Difference (MMD) distance, with the class of functions taken to be the unit ball of an Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$:
$$
\textsf{MMD}_\varphi(P,Q)=\big\|\mathbb{E}_{X\sim P}[\varphi(X)]-\mathbb{E}_{Y\sim Q}[\varphi(Y)]\big\|_\mathcal{H},
$$
where $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathcal{H}$. In this post I am essentially interested in the case where $\varphi$ is related to the Gaussian kernel by:
$$
\big\langle\varphi(x),\varphi(y)\big\rangle_\mathcal{H}=k(x,y)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}|x-y|^2\right).
$$

I am interested in what are the differences between these distances. For example, it seems to me that:

$\mathsf{W}_1$ compares how quantiles or mass repartition differ in the distributions (note: I am aware of the optimal transport interpretation of $\mathsf{W}_1$), while $\mathsf{TVD}$ compare mass but at the "atomic level" so to say, because it involve the PDFs, so it would be "tighter",
The particular instance of $\textsf{MMD}_\varphi$ above is going to compare all the moments between the two distributions, which, if we think in terms of dispersion, skewness and kurtosis, then would put some emphasis on the "geometric shapes" of the distributions.
On the numerical side, supposing $P$ and $Q$ to be unknown, if I am given samples from $P$ and $Q$ then for $\mathsf{TVD}$ I will have to estimate the PDFs and approximate the integral. Same thing for $\mathsf{W}_1$: the CDFs need to be estimated and the integral approximated. However, for $\textsf{MMD}_\varphi$, using the kernel trick it is easy to obtain a "plug-in" estimator for the distance.

Which are the usecases in statistics/data science/machine learning where you would use one distance over the others, and why? Does somebody have simple examples that can explain the differences between these three distances? Thanks for any help!

Your first (TVD) would be useless when comparing a continuous distribution with a discrete distribution (so for example you would not get Central Limit Theorem type convergence of distributions).

Just checking...my understanding is that $TV = {\frac{1}{2}}\int|p(x)-q(x)| dx$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481101/definition-of-the-total-variation-distance-vp-q-frac12-int-p-qd-n (and numerous other references)

Here are some points, I'm not completely sure for some of them which I have highlighted with a (?)

TV and W1 (over R) can both be formulated as the maximal difference of expected values for a given function $f$:

for TV, this is over bounded functions:
$$
    d_{TV}(X, Y) = \max_{f, |f| \leq 1} \mathbb E [ f(X) ] - \mathbb E [ f(Y) ]
    $$

for W1, is it for lipchitz 1 functions (??)

other metrics can be expressed in this way

for a good summary and presentation, see chapter 1 and 2 of Chen, Goldstein, Shao: Normal approximations by Stein's method; further chapters deal with applications of these properties. It's a great book



TV has peculiar features:

it is invariant to bijective changes of variable: I really like this property
it is maximal between a discrete and continuous variable so the gaussian limit of the binomial is not true in total-variation


Wassertein-1, and other wasserstein distances, have a great definition in terms of optimizing how to move the mass between the probability densities. This has been a very hot topic in probability and machine learning in the last 15 years. These lecture notes by Villani could be a possible introduction

Overall, in practical work, the considerations are:

what is the metric (or pseudo-metric) that is computationally practical
what is the metric which gives the right kind of control of my approximation


Similarly, in theoretical work:

what is the metric (or pseudo-metric, again) that makes my math doable and simple
what is the metric from which I can derive correct control



In practice, there is a lot of Kullback-Leibler divergence, a lot of Wasserstein (there is an approximate optimization method, but I've forgotten its name and I can't recall it). Total variation is a bit more marginal. I don't think I've seen a lot of this MMD idea.
